# Getting Heap size error in jmeter i.e memory out of heap

Tags: jmeter

I have already changed the jmeter.bat size to set `HEAP=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m`. But after changing heap size I am still getting a heap size error message. What do I need to do.

For error message seen below:

```
2015/11/18 14:52:40 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:100000ms 
2015/11/18 14:52:51 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:25000ms 
2015/11/18 14:53:38 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:140000ms 
2015/11/18 14:53:41 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:20000ms 
2015/11/18 14:54:23 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:180000ms 
2015/11/18 14:54:34 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:20000ms 
2015/11/18 14:55:13 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TS_stage 1-41 
2015/11/18 14:55:13 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TS_stage 1-41 
2015/11/18 14:55:14 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:50000ms 
2015/11/18 14:55:38 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:20000ms 
2015/11/18 14:56:00 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:120000ms 
2015/11/18 14:56:04 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:140000ms 
2015/11/18 14:56:36 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:50000ms 
2015/11/18 14:57:08 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:80000ms 
2015/11/18 14:57:29 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:160000ms 
2015/11/18 14:58:46 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:80000ms 
2015/11/18 14:59:09 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:140000ms 
2015/11/18 14:59:50 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:100000ms 
2015/11/18 15:01:16 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:180000ms 
2015/11/18 15:02:16 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TS_stage 1-39 
2015/11/18 15:02:16 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TS_stage 1-39 
2015/11/18 15:02:19 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TS_stage 1-35 
2015/11/18 15:02:19 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TS_stage 1-35 
2015/11/18 15:02:33 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TS_stage 1-44 
2015/11/18 15:02:33 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TS_stage 1-44 
2015/11/18 15:02:38 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TS_stage 1-37 
2015/11/18 15:02:38 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TS_stage 1-37 
2015/11/18 15:02:58 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:160000ms 
2015/11/18 15:03:05 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:120000ms 
2015/11/18 15:06:15 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:140000ms 
2015/11/18 15:07:01 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:180000ms 
2015/11/18 15:07:49 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TS_stage 1-45 
2015/11/18 15:07:49 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TS_stage 1-45 
2015/11/18 15:07:53 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TS_stage 1-34 
2015/11/18 15:07:53 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TS_stage 1-34 
2015/11/18 15:09:35 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:160000ms 
2015/11/18 15:13:41 WARN  - jmeter.timers.SyncTimer: SyncTimer Synchronizing Timer timeouted waiting for users after:180000ms 
2015/11/18 15:14:44 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TS_stage 1-50 
2015/11/18 15:14:44 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TS_stage 1-50 
2015/11/18 15:14:55 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TS_stage 1-47 
2015/11/18 15:14:55 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TS_stage 1-47 
2015/11/18 15:20:34 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: TS_stage 1-49 
2015/11/18 15:20:34 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TS_stage 1-49 
2015/11/18 15:45:11 INFO  - jmeter.gui.action.Start: Stopping test 
2015/11/18 15:45:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TS_stage 1-31 
2015/11/18 15:45:11 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TS_stage 1-31 sampler: hotels 
2015/11/18 15:45:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TS_stage 1-28 
2015/11/18 15:45:11 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TS_stage 1-28 sampler: spa 
2015/11/18 15:45:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TS_stage 1-27 
2015/11/18 15:45:11 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TS_stage 1-27 sampler: nightlife-lounges 
2015/11/18 15:45:11 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Interrupted in thread TS_stage 1-28 java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1232)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1346)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.runSafe(JMeterUtils.java:1322)
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.SummaryReport.add(SummaryReport.java:182)
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.sendToVisualizer(ResultCollector.java:595)
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.sampleOccurred(ResultCollector.java:571)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.ListenerNotifier.notifyListeners(ListenerNotifier.java:84)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.notifyListeners(JMeterThread.java:796)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:456)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

2015/11/18 15:45:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TS_stage 1-28 
2015/11/18 15:45:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stopping: TS_stage 1-33 
2015/11/18 15:45:11 WARN  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Interrupting: TS_stage 1-33 sampler: vip service 
2015/11/18 15:45:11 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Interrupted in thread TS_stage 1-31 java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1232)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1346)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.runSafe(JMeterUtils.java:1322)
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.SummaryReport.add(SummaryReport.java:182)
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.sendToVisualizer(ResultCollector.java:595)
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.sampleOccurred(ResultCollector.java:571)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.ListenerNotifier.notifyListeners(ListenerNotifier.java:84)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.notifyListeners(JMeterThread.java:796)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:456)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

2015/11/18 15:45:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TS_stage 1-31 
2015/11/18 15:45:11 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Interrupted in thread TS_stage 1-33 java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1232)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1346)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.runSafe(JMeterUtils.java:1322)
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.SummaryReport.add(SummaryReport.java:182)
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.sendToVisualizer(ResultCollector.java:595)
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.sampleOccurred(ResultCollector.java:571)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.ListenerNotifier.notifyListeners(ListenerNotifier.java:84)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.notifyListeners(JMeterThread.java:796)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:456)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

2015/11/18 15:45:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TS_stage 1-33 
2015/11/18 15:45:11 WARN  - jmeter.util.JMeterUtils: Interrupted in thread TS_stage 1-27 java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1232)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1346)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.runSafe(JMeterUtils.java:1322)
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.SummaryReport.add(SummaryReport.java:182)
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.sendToVisualizer(ResultCollector.java:595)
    at org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector.sampleOccurred(ResultCollector.java:571)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.ListenerNotifier.notifyListeners(ListenerNotifier.java:84)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.notifyListeners(JMeterThread.java:796)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:456)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

2015/11/18 15:45:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: TS_stage 1-27 
2015/11/18 15:45:11 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2015/11/18 15:45:11 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

Comment: I think your error is different than question.

Comment: Your error is issue of timer which you are using. I think no concern with heap size.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not error, it is warning
2. It is not connected to heap size by any means

You're using Synchronising Timer presumably to kick off some request by multiple threads at the same time. The warning is about you don't have enough threads to group. Just increase "Number of Threads (users)" at [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level and that should be it.

See [Using the JMeter Synchronizing Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) guide for comprehensive information on the web element.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following remedies :

- Remove all the listeners that you have in your Jmeter test plan. Try restarting and then see what happens.
- If the above step doesn't remove's the errors, try running Jmeter in a non-GUI mode using

  ```
  jmeter -n -t testplan.jmx -r
  ```

These should do away the errors.